# Number of countries for billing and Shipping to be different in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to display some countries in shipping address and some other countries in the billing address.
I have followed the suggestion provided [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/59566/#t186374) .But after doing that my state/province input box doesn't appear.
Like this ->

[image]

Comment: works for me on 1.7.0.2   What version are you using?  You sure you didnt change some other code?  This shouldn't happen.  Replace the original code and you will prob still be missing a box...

Answer (score 0):

look at line 78 ish in (path_to_magento)\app\design\frontend\default(my_skin_name)\template\checkout\onepage\shipping.phtml

and it should be like this. Maybe you deleted something -

```
   <div class="field">
                        <label for="shipping:region" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select id="shipping:region_id" name="shipping[region_id]" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                                <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                            </select>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            //<![CDATA[
                                $('shipping:region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "<?php echo $this->getAddress()->getRegionId() ?>");
                            //]]>
                            </script>
                            <input type="text" id="shipping:region" name="shipping[region]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text" style="display:none;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```